# Warning: POST Content-Length of 20616317 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0

Tags: joomla2.5

I am completely new to Joomla. I am trying to upload a template on Joomla 2.5, but it keeps coming up with this error:

`Warning: POST Content-Length of 20616317 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0`

I don't know where to go. I have read about max limit but I don't know how to change it or which file it's in. Can anyone suggest where I might look?

Comment: If you are considering just a Joomla template upload - just increase the post_max_size(all the current uploads together) and possibly upload_max_filesize(for single file)... however if you want to hide the error if someone would try to upload too large files (over your limits) see... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21704930/how-to-prevent-warning-post-content-length-and-memory-size

Answer (score 7):

You are trying to upload a file with nearly 20MB, but PHPs max accepted POST-size is set to 8MB by default. You will have to increase two php variables `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` to at least 20MB.

There are several ways to do this:

1. If you have direct access to the server config, modify it in the `php.ini` directly.
2. If you are on a shared hosting site, it may be possible to change the size by either creating a local `php.ini`, or by `.htaccess` flags. However, many hosters restrict increasing this value. You should consider the help documents of your hoster. Search for the variable names.

Comment: Thank you for your response, however i can not find this Upload_max_file size, and the size is not hosted. i don't even know where to find the php.ini

Comment: What do you mean, your site is not hosted? Do you have a local server?
In Joomla's backend, go to Site -> System Information, then open the Tab Php Informations. In the first block, you will find "Loaded Configuration File", this is the path to the php.ini. There you can change the values. Don't forget to restart your webserver.
Further down this very long list, you can also find the active values for both variables.