# Zend Validator Size for File Uploading Form - Zend Framework 2.3

Tags: php, validation, file-upload, zend-framework2, size

I have a problem with Zend\Validator\File\Size;

I have a File input Uploader and I have set its validator like this:

```
$fileInput->getValidatorChain()
    ->attach(new Validator\File\Size(array('min' => '10kB', 'max' => '4MB')))
    ->attach(new Validator\File\UploadFile())
    ->attach(new Validator\File\isImage());
```

So, this code works fine but Validator\Size doesn't work correctly. if I try to upload a file is between 4mb to 8mb works correctly and dipslay "File exceeds the defined ini size", when I try to upload a file bigger than 8mb, it's display this error:

```
Warning: POST Content-Length of 9469269 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0
```

my php.ini

upload_max_filesize=8M
post_max_size=8M

I want display the validation's error "File exceeds the defined ini size" also the file's size is bigger than 8Mb. I don't understand because doesn't happen it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `upload_max_filesize` & `post_max_size` should be bigger than 8M if you want to handle 8M as a max limit, or else you will receive those warnings.

if you are annoyed by those warning, this is a way to avoid them:
[How to prevent Warning: POST Content-Length and memory size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21704930/how-to-prevent-warning-post-content-length-and-memory-size)

Comment: I want upload some images, but each image must be lower than 4Mb and it's the reason than I have put the max size limit at 4Mb.

Comment: as I explained, you need to make the max limit higher than 4M, download the image check the size return an error message and delete the image in case it is bigger than 4M, the other option is to get rid of those warnings.